# Can NLog performance counters be configured to monitor AsyncWrapper queue sizes?

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm using NLog v2.0 with an AsyncWrapper and a custom target. I would like to monitor the size of the AsyncWrapper target queueSize. I have configured the AsyncWrapper as follows.

```
<target xsi:type="AsyncWrapper"
        name="CustomTargetWrapper"
        queueLimit="100000"
        overflowAction="Discard">
      <target xsi:type="CustomTarget" name="MyTarget" ... />
    </target>
```

I see NLog supports Performance Counters. I believe it's easy enough to add a performance counter to see the number of Writes, Average number of writes and so on, but it doesn't look like I can monitor an AsyncWrapper queue size. There are some TODO comments in the notes for NLog performance counters so maybe it's not quite production ready - http://nlog-project.org/wiki/PerfCounter_target

Can NLog performance counters be configured to monitor AsyncWrapper queue sizes?